# How to get the name of font by a TextView or EditText in android?

Tags: android, android-fonts, android-typeface

I want to get the name of font set up on a textview, I am able to get Typeface but cant get the exact font name. I've setup new font on textview as following...

```
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Segoe UI Light"));
```

Can I get back **Segoe UI Light**?

Comment: Not in any way that I see immediately (looking at both TextView and Typeface classes). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Sir actually I have to store the properties of textview, It is a text editor. Whenever user want to edit the text again, he must get the old preferences. I hope you got it.

Comment: Have you tried getStyle() method of Typeface class?

Comment: @Keshav getStyle() just listing some keywords like cast, field, fori, forr, par, return etc. After all it will return an int value, How can I get name?

Comment: @KhanSquare The font name which you have set before must be shown right, cant you save the name when you set the font and get it back when needed? Will this work out for you?

Comment: @Keshav Yeah I already did it, because it is the last option.